# GNOME suddenly bugged after rebooting

Tags: fedora, gnome

After restarting my computer, the appearance of GNOME has suddenly changed. Now it looks like this:

[image]

When it should look more like this:

[image]

I don't know if there is any way to go back to the layout as before, I tried resetting the configuration with `gnome-tweaks` and it didn't work. I have seen that some animations are bugged, so I deduce that it could be a bug.

I'm currently using **Fedora 37 Workstation Edition**, with **GNOME 43.3**

Comment: that looks like for some reason, a different session / window manager than gnome was started. Can you "log out", and on the log-in screen, make sure that "Gnome" is selected (depending on your display manager, that selection is a dropdown menu or hidden behind a gear symbol or such)

Comment: @MarcusMüller When I log out and I click "Change user", It goes back to the correct GNOME layout. But as soon as I type my password and I press enter, it goes back to the incorrect layout :/ But there's not a gear symbol or anything similar at the login screen

Comment: it's not "bugged", it's simply not Gnome :) I don't have the default fedora login manager at hand, but if I remember somewhat correctly, the gears appear after you have entered your username, but before you press "enter" after entering your password.